# bitaddress.org: is the public key the same as the Bitcoin address?

Tags: wallet, address, public-key, paper-wallet, bitaddress.org

For paper wallets generated at bitaddress.org, are the public keys and BTC addresses the same thing?

Comment: You could read more about bitcoin addresses on bitcoin.it
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses#How_to_create_Bitcoin_Address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they're not the same thing. Paper wallets are not generated differently as/in to comparison to normal wallets.

a bitcoin adress is part of a public key.

> The address is at its most basic just a hash of the public key. The hash functions involved (RIPEMD-160 and SHA256) are cryptographic hash functions. They are often also referred to as one-way functions, which is exactly the reason why you cannot derive the public key from the address.
>
> Oneway functions provide exactly that a = f(pk) so that given a you cannot derive pk.

So, an adress is basically the hash of a public key. x/x

Some good more indepth explanations of the differences here -> https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/3filud/whats_the_difference_between_public_key_and/ctp3fc7/?st=jald5nmq&sh=620d5934

And, how the adress is derived from the public key is explained here ->

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, if I access bitaddress.org to create a paper wallet and generate a pair of public key and private key, how do I know what my Bitcoin address is if I want to send Bitcoins to that wallet?

Comment: You will need to generate an adress using the public key of the wallet.

Comment: I have read the links, but it is still not clear to me how I obtain the Bitcoin address so I can store BTC there. I want to make sure I'm sending the BTC to the right address.

Comment: So, you've currently generated a Bitcoin public key + private key, right?  You will either need to put that private key + public key  into a wallet, or tool to create an adress, Or, use something like bitadress.org to create a paper wallet, and they will make a set of adresses for you. ( Always make sure you're disconnected from the internet before generating!)

Comment: There's been some answers here which had links to tools you could use client side / offline, but i can't find them right now. Something like this should work aswell -> https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49544/is-there-a-tool-to-produce-addresses-given-a-master-public-key

Comment: @UserX bitaddress.org gives you the private key and the associated receiving address (not the public key).